# "namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required" error persists after reinstalling vctrs

Tags: r, namespaces, libraries, install.packages

I am trying to load the tidyverse library (and constituent libraries) but:

```
rm(list=ls())

.libPaths("C:\\Users\\Me\\OneDrive\\Documents\\R\\R_libraries")

library(twitteR)
library(tidyverse)
```

gives the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.3.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.8 is required
```

I reset the environment, went into the "R_libraries" folder, deleted the 'vctrs' folder, and ran install.packages('vctrs'). vctrs installed successfully and while installing said it was version 0.3.8.

I loaded tidyverse successfully and worked on my script.

However this morning I tried to run it and I am getting the same error message above again. Why would version 0.3.6 be loaded if it was deleted and 0.3.8 installed instead? How do I stop it?

This seems to be a repeated issue (this time it is with vctrs but I have had it for other packages in the past), is there anything I can do to stop this from occurring and automatically update all packages once new versions are available rather than causing conflicts with all the dependent packages?

Comment: Do you load a workspace file when starting R or RStudio? Uncheck the relevant setting in the options menu if you do (because you should never do so or at least only do it manually).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was doing this by default. I've unchecked the box now and it seems to let me load the correct version!